# Removing the last element in an array

Tags: arrays, numbers, distinct, splice

This is a question about finding distinct values in an array of ten numbers. The user provides 10 numbers. I've written the code, separated the code into two files(another condition to the assignment) but I found myself at a loss when the answer returns with a trailing 0.

I need to know how to remove the trailing 0 from the array. If it was a string I could do this easily. Unfortunately, I need to return the answer as an array between the two files.

I have researched the topic and found that "splice" works but I can't figure out how it works in my code. The only solution that I came up with is to remove all 0s from the code (my first example below). Unfortunately, the user should be able to include 0s if he or she decides to input a zero.

```
//document 1
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strOfArray = " ";
        String Values = "";

       int arr[]=new int[1000000];
          System.out.print("Entered 10 integers:\t\t\t ");

           for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
                arr[i] = s.nextInt();

           for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
                strOfArray += (arr[j]+ " ");

           System.out.println ("Array before processing:"+ "\t" + strOfArray);

       System.out.print("Array after processing:\t\t ");
```

DistinctValues.getValues(arr);

```
       }
}

//document 2
public class DistinctValues {

   public static void getValues(int[] arr){
   String Values = "";
      for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         boolean isUnique = false;

      for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
         if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
            isUnique = true;
            break;}}

            if(!isUnique){ 
               System.out.print(arr[i] +" ");}}}}
```

I added all my code for better clarification. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript code here ? please use relevant tags

Comment: You are mixing javascript `splice` with Java array, better you look into `Arrays.copyOfRange` for Java.

Comment: Confused. Your question says *javascript* but you are writing java code.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the solution after trial and error and me realizing that I had a set number of elements so I didn't need to be ambiguous about what I set "i" to. Since I have 10 variables, I could just make it i one less than 10 and the program couldn't spit out an extra 0.

```
    if(!isUnique && i<10){ 
           System.out.print(arr[i] +" ");}
```

But since I'm learning this. Can someone help me with an array that wasn't set to 10 integers or set to however many the user wanted. Make it i < variable?